# simple email form joomla captcha not showing in firefox because of backslash

Tags: forms, email, joomla

i was wondering if this is a bug or not. i tried this simple email form with image captcha. it was working until i tested it with mozilla firefox. The images can't be displayed because of the url of images becomes "\" instead of "/" . any help?

Comment: can you share some code please?

Comment: no, it's an extension from joomla. so i don't really understand why